# How to Enable Tile Caching

Tags: leaflet, heremaps

HERE maps refers to tile-caching by using the cache-control header option (see: [Cache Maps](https://developer.here.com/documentation/raster-tile-api/dev_guide/topics/cache-maps.html)). Which I could do if I was making my own GET requests; but I am using the Leaflet API, and so was wondering if anyone knows how to enable tile caching within Leaflet.

Perhaps it's not possible since Leaflet is just Javascript and CSS. But then, is there a different way to enable tile caching (like through Apache header directives or something)? I don't really want to cache the whole page, just the map tiles if it's possible.

I tried passing "maxAge" and "max-age" in to the tile layer's options, but it (unsurprisingly) had no effect.

If I can't get this to work, then I'll probably look into database caching (about which there seems to be more information). But I imagine doing it this way would be significantly easier for the time being.